# Can't retieve a value from a C function in a Python script but can in console

Tags: python, ctypes

I am using python (Pydev) to communicate with stepper motors with a DLL using ctypes. I am trying to retrieve the position of the motor. The thing is that if I type the script in line by line in the console it works but if I run the script it always gives me 0.
This is my code:

```
import ctypes

AC=windll.hvpositionerv2
adr=addressof
class PositionerInfo (Structure):
    _fields_=[("id",c_int),("locked",c_bool)]

ptr=POINTER(PositionerInfo)()
devCount=AC.PositionerCheck(adr(ptr))
print("Devices found: "+repr(devCount))
for i in range(min(adr(ptr),devCount)):
     print("ID: "+repr(ptr[i].id)+" Locked? "+repr(ptr[i].locked))

handle=POINTER(c_int)()
AC.PositionerConnect(0,adr(handle))
```

So far the program has only connected to the device. Now, the problem is this:

```
ypos=c_int()
AC.PositionerGetPosition(handle,1,adr(ypos)

print(ypos.value)
```

This always prints 0 if I run the script (in Eclipse) but works in the console.

Comment: Have you tried running this outside of eclipse?  It may be that it can't find the DLL needed when running in eclipse and the code happens to still run and print 0?  Otherwise it could be a timing issue.

Comment: May be a namespace clash, the dll has the same name as a python module that is listed first on pythons path?

Comment: What are the C function prototypes?  Also, to pass by reference, you can use `handle=c_int()` and then use `byref(handle)` in the function parameter.  What is going on with the range()?  Why take the min of a adr(ptr) and the devCount?

Answer (score 0):

My best guess: this is a timing issue. After connecting to the hardware, it takes a certain amount of time before it reports the motor position, and before that first response, you will always get 0. Try adding a 1 second sleep before AC.PositionerGetPosition.